# サイトから勝手にログアウトされてしまう

Tags: バグ

PC での閲覧時、サイトから突然ログアウトされてしまう現象が度々発生します。
(正確な時期は覚えていませんが、数か月前から断続的に発生)

特定の動作を行った時という感じではなく、単純なページの移動やリロードしたタイミングでいきなりログアウトされた状態になります。
問題が発生するのは PC 版で、ブラウザのタブは基本的に開きっぱなしでキャッシュの削除等は行っていません。
発生の頻度も特に法則性は無くて、数日程度経ってからの場合もあれば、ログインし直した数時間後に発生する場合もあります。なお、スマホ版では特に発生した記憶がありません。

また、参考になるか分かりませんが、スタックオーバーフロー (MSE) 以外のサイトでは同じブラウザで開いていても勝手にログアウトされるような現象は発生していません。

複数のPC (Windows 10) で発生し、ブラウザは Firefox、Opera を使用しています。